# How to use jks file directly in POSTMAN for https REST end-point

Tags: rest, postman

I have an .jks certificate, i am able to use this for a request in Soap UI.

In SoapUI, I used the GET rest endpoint and saved it as project, then added the JKS at project level.

[image]

Next I expanded the projects and at the End-point configuration, selected the JKS file in the properties and added it (refer below snapshot).

With this setup i am successfully hitting the REST endpoint and getting a 200 OK response.

[image]

I am trying to see if i can use the POSTMAN to do the same, but it doesn't take the jks file.

It looks for cer, pem, crt files, which either i need to create from jks file. Is there any way to use the jks file directly in Postman.

Comment: please try this https://blog.postman.com/importing-soapui-projects-into-postman/